# Why do I get errors cs1502 and cs1503 in my Destroy object script?

Tags: unity

I have a script that lets the player place blocks (like in Minecraft), but I also want to be able to destroy those blocks. I keep getting error messages cs1502 and cs1503.

Could anyone take a look at the script and tell me what is wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestForCube : MonoBehaviour {

  Ray ray;
  RaycastHit hit;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {

    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {

      if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Mouse0)) {

        Vector3 position = hit.transform.position + hit.normal ;
        Quaternion rotation =  Quaternion.FromToRotation( Vector3.up , hit.normal );
        GameObject Placement = GameObject.CreatePrimitive( PrimitiveType.Cube );
        Placement.transform.position = position;
        Placement.transform.rotation = rotation;
      }

      {
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
          if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Mouse1)) {
            DestroyObject( PrimitiveType.Cube);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What lines are producing the errors? Did you search for it ([cs1502](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1502), [cs1503](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1503))?

Answer (score 2):

The line that's giving you the errors is this:

```cs
DestroyObject(PrimitiveType.Cube);
```

The `DestroyObject` method requires an `Object` type parameter, but you're passing a `UnityEngine.PrimitiveType` `enum` type.

It's not completely clear what you want to achieve, but if you want to destroy a game object when it's clicked with the right mouse button, you should keep the references to the game objects you create when clicking the left mouse button and use `Destroy` instead of `DestroyObject`.

Comment: thank you, what do you mean by keeping the references?

Comment: A reference is the `GameObject Placement` variable value that you used before in the code. That variable keeps a reference to the game object just instantiated, so that after you can manipulate that game object by using the `Placement` variable. That variable, though, is local in scope, it means that it will be destroyed as soon as you exit the `{}` of the `if` condition. So you need to have a class scope variable (or list of variables) of type `GameObject` that will keep the reference to the objects you create, in order to use them anywhere inside the class.

Comment: hmmm, I see. Would I have to state the GameObject or something else as public? I tried that earlier but it didn't work. I have much to learn

Comment: Before diving into Unity, I'd suggest you learn the basics of OOP and C#, like what are reference and value types variables, their scope, etc. You need those concepts in order to write even basic scripts. You should find a lot of material regarding basic concepts just by googling.